# unexpected error 1054 in sql

Tags: mysql, alter-table

After table setup, I suddenly remember to update it by adding one column and assign all the same value to that column. So I wrote the queries on Workbench like this

```
ALTER TABLE sthebc3_cle ADD COLUMN Species char(30) AFTER Genome_ACC;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE cle.sthebc3_cle
SET Species='StHe';
```

But it reported error like

```
error 1054: unknown column "Species" in "field list
```

I checked table after `ALTER`, The new column "Species" was indeed added to the column and values are NULL.

How could be the error reported?

Comment: Just to make sure are you using the database cle in the alter statement? You didnt create the column in a test enviroment maybe?

Comment: Yes. It is. I tried to remove the "cle." and it still didn't work

Comment: And if you run SELECT Species FROM sthbec3_cle WHERE Species IS NULL you get a list of rows?

Comment: it worked out by adding USE cle. That is weird, but it worked anyway. Thank you. I have question about what you said about test environment. Since I tried to UNION two tables in cle schema into VIEW, it reports the same error again. (Those two tables have the exactly the same column)

Comment: The script like thisUSE cle;
CREATE VIEW all_cle AS
( SELECT Species, Genome_ACC, CLE_start, CLE_end, CLE_domain FROM cowpea_cle)
 UNION 
(SELECT Species, Genome_ACC, CLE_start, CLE_end, CLE_domain FROM sthebc3_cle);

Comment: i wrote you a answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the current session is the database you want. There is always a selected database in `MySQL`.

If you want to be 100% sure which database you are using you Always put `nameofthedatabase.tablename`,

For the table

```
ALTER TABLE cle.sthebc3_cle ADD COLUMN Species char(30) AFTER Genome_ACC;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE cle.sthebc3_cle
SET Species='StHe';
```

For you view, try this

```
USE cle; 
CREATE VIEW all_cle AS 
(SELECT Species, Genome_ACC, CLE_start, CLE_end, CLE_domain 
  FROM nameofdatabase.cowpea_cle) 
UNION 
(SELECT Species, Genome_ACC, CLE_start, CLE_end, CLE_domain 
 FROM nameofdatabase.sthebc3_cle);
```

Comment: The VIEW still doesn't work. both of cowpea_cle and sthebc3_cle are in the cle database. So I replace the "nameofdatabase" with "cle". However, Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Species' in 'field list'.

Comment: Have you created the column in cle.cowpea_cle?